# Android Strings with apostrophe

Tags: android

How to add apostrophe in Android String Resource File? 
Hi!,
I'm trying to add apostrophe (') in android strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Stack's Answers</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Stack\'s Answers</string>
</resources>
```

You have to escape the XML with a \ before the apostrophe because it is a character that has a special meaning in Android's XML.

Comment: This works fine, but I'll add the comment  that you can't use the xml escape &apos; as a substitute.  It'll still give you the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Stack\'s Answers</string>
</resources>
```